# Avoiding KVO Obervers for RESTKit calls

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, key-value-observing, restkit-0.20

I m trying to implement dateModified updation using KVO Observers as shown here

https://github.com/dvidsilva/everpobre/blob/master/coreData/DVDNoteModel.m

But the problem is this is also being called when RESTKit is fetching data from server and storing it locally in CoreData, which I dont want.

I need to avoid triggering KVO observers only for the RESTKit calls, so when RESTKit fetches data from server it must not get updated with dataModified.

Furthermore I found out that RESTKit calls are being initiated from [RKResponseMapperOperation main] so using [NSThread callStackSymbols] although I m able to successfully track it and execute it, this solution is functional for Build version only (installed on devices) but for Release version [NSThread callStackSymbols] isn't returning same symbols leaving RESTKit call untracked.

I am unable to track if current call is RESTKit or my own.

```
Is there a way to track if current Thread call is from RESTKit?
or 
Is there a way we could track it using RESTKit NSManagedObjectContext or so?
or any other possible solution?
```

Please answer if you have any possible hint.

Thanks.

Comment: Use lldb and symbolic breakpoint on ManagedObjectContext save: method, and your method call and try to figure it out.

Comment: I tried doing it using [NSThread callStackSymbols] & tracking [RKResponseMapperOperation main], but this isn't functional for Release version. any suggesstion

Comment: What is your ultimate aim? However you make changes they will always propagate up to context hierarchy and result in change notifications, that's the underpinning of how Core Data works. Once you get away from the background context save that RestKit does you can't tell where the merge originated. You could maybe get the will/did save notifications and disable your listeners during a merge if it's from a background thread...

Comment: Wain, I was actually waiting for your input, my aim is simple, I wants to keep modifying "dateModified" for each of my NSManagedObjects (using KVO Observers or so) whenever there is change in it except for RESTKit. once RESTKit is loading data for RKEntityMapping objects, its creating NSManagedObjects to persist in coredata, while doing coredata operations RESTKit is overwriting "dateModified" in KVO Observers for all NSManagedObjects which is coming from server, which I dont want, there must be some suitable solution to identify RESTKit calls to avoid KVO observers for that particular call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RKEntityMapping`'s `modificationKey` to accomplish exactly this. There are a few requirements though:

1. It only works on a single key. This could be a modification date, hash, etc. Anything that always changes when the rest of the object changes.
2. Your JSON must also contain this key.

If you have both of those, RestKit will check to see if the destination object's modificationKey matches the JSON. If it does not modification will occur and it won't trigger KVO.

Comment: Thanks patrick, I have dateModified which is changing when objects changes and JSON also contain dateModified in it, so both requirements are followed, please let me know how I could make it RKEntityMapping's modificationKey to achieve my desired requirement

Comment: Just set the modification key to dateModified.